# Returning a Task from a base method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, async-await, uwp

I am still in the process of getting a handle on asynchronous programming and a bit puzzled on how to modify the following:

**base virtual method:**

```
public virtual async Task OnSuspendingAsync(object s, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
     // do some housekeeping actions upon suspending in the base class

     await Task.Yield();
}
```

**overriding method:**

```
public override Task OnSuspendingAsync(object s, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
     // do some housekeeping actions on exiting/suspending

     return base.OnSuspendingAsync(s, e);
}
```

**the question:**

Now if I use an awaitable in the overridden method (almost unavoidable), I need to change `public override Task` to `public override async Task` by adding the `async` keyword as illustrated with a real example below.

```
public override async Task OnSuspendingAsync(object s, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     // tidy up app temporary folder on exit
     await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync(ApplicationDataLocality.Temporary);
   }
   catch { }

   return base.OnSuspendingAsync(s, e); // this is wrong with awaitable!
}
```

In this case what should be the `return base.OnSuspendingAsync(s, e);` change to (and why) which Visual Studio is rightly flagging as an error?

Comment: Wouldn't you just await the base method?

Comment: Tried  `return await base.OnSuspendingAsync(s, e);`  already and thought it must be something more as Visual Studio still flags an error. That's what puzzled me.

Comment: No, just replace `return` with `await`.

Comment: You're right Glorin. But why should `await` replace the `return`? I just want to understand the mechanics in a logical way. Please reply as an Answer so that I can tag it as answered. Explanation is appreciated in your answer.

Comment: In your first overridden example, you are returning a `Task` generated by `base.OnSuspendingAsync()`. You aren't doing anything other than passing it on to the caller of your overridden method. In your second overridden example, your method is generating a *new* `Task` by virtue of being async. Your `Task` doesn't return anything, thus your return statement is erroneous. You're simply wanting to `await` your base task.

Comment: Think of it this way... if you declare your method as `async Task` as opposed to `async Task<T>`... it is much like a `void` method. It doesn't directly return any kind of *result*. Simply the `Task` which is doing the work.

Comment: Thank you Glorin. I follow your points if the auto generated code line `return base.OnSuspendingAsync(s, e); ` wasn't there.  
Care to comment on this one please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `await` the result:

```
public override async Task OnSuspendingAsync(object s, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     // tidy up app temporary folder on exit
     await ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync(ApplicationDataLocality.Temporary);
   }
   catch { }

   await base.OnSuspendingAsync(s, e);
}
```

Before you had `await` in the method, it was fine for the method to run synchronously. You could do your synchronous logic, and then call the asynchronous base method and just pass the returned `Task` object it uses to track its progress as your own return value.

But once you introduce `await` into your method, now your own method is asynchronous. It will return at the very first `await`, and the `Task` returned to the caller represents the entire sequence of work your method will perform.

You want to make sure that `Task` is not indicating a completion until the base method's `Task` itself has indicated a completion. So the last thing you need to do in your now-asynchronous method is `await` the result of the base method. In doing so, your method effectively doesn't terminate until after that happens, and thus its own `Task` object (representing its own work) will not indicate completion until the base method's does.

Note that this is not the only possible way to address your scenario. But IMHO it is the most readable and simple to implement.

**ADDENDUM:**

I thought the above was sufficient to explain why `await` is used, but perhaps not. To elaborate on the above, and in particular to answer the question "why is `return` replaced by `await`?":

1. It's important to understand that the `return` statement isn't *literally* being replaced. In some contexts, `return await` is correct. I.e. when the `async` method does in fact return a value and that value is produced by some awaitable operation.
2. So where did the `return` statement go? Well: when you create an `async` method, the return type changes. Instead of being the actual value returned by the method with a `return` statement, the method's return type must be `void`, `Task`, or `Task<T>` (where `T` is of course some actual type or a defined type parameter).
   Here we must use `Task` because that's the method signature we have to comply with. But note that we use `Task` when no actual value is returned (i.e. the method would otherwise be `void`). So our `async` method must not return anything. You can write `return;`, but not `return <some value>;`. I opted to omit the return entirely, but if you prefer having it, you can add `return`; *after* the second `await...`
3. Why was `await` added. I hope this is more clear, per my explanation above. It's what causes the execution of the method to be temporarily suspended while the `base.OnSuspendingAsync()` method is doing it's work (asynchronously). It works with `async` to indicate to the compiler a point in the method when it can return, and then where execution will resume next.
   Using `await` is what ensures the `Task` returned by your `OnSuspendingAsync()` override does not indicate completion until the base implementation has itself completed.